# How to get list as an input from command line python?

Tags: python, string, list

I know that we can use sys.argv, but I am having an issue with this.

I want to pass a list as an argument :

```
Example [5,1,6,[5,2]]
```

This is a nested list and I want to take it as input the way it is.

```
python myprogram.py [5,1,6,[5,2]]
```

This is my program:

```
import sys;


input_list = sys.argv[1].split(',')
print(input_list)
```

I did obtain the list, however if I output it, it is completely wrong structurally:

```
['[5', '1', '6', '[5', '2]]']
```

As you can see, instead of `input_list[0] == 5` , I have it equal to `'[5'`, also the nested list that I inputted now is no more nested. Instead of `input_list[3] ==[5,2]`, `input_list[3] is equal to '[5'`.

What should I do? I need to take the list as it is in order to work with it.

Comment: You *could* `eval()` it, but I'd rather suggest you look at the `argparse` module to see if that can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import ast

input_list = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
```

then the output will be

```
[5, 1, 6, [5, 2]]
```

Comment: Note that you have to hand the args as an explicit string like `python myprogram.py "[5, 1, 6, [5, 2]]"`

Comment: @BreakBB Yes thanks

Comment: A minimal explanation of what is going on under the scenes would be helpful to help OP progress IMHO. But that is present in the duplicate